# Using Magento's addFieldToFilter to filter by existing columns

Tags: php, orm, magento, entity-attribute-value

Hypothetical situation. I want to populate/load a `sales/order` collection with every order where the grand_total is equal to the `total_paid`.  I know I can use `addFieldToFilter` to filter by a specific value, but is it possible to use this method to filter by other database values.  If not, is there any data access object in the Magento system that allows this.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$orders = $orders->getCollection();
$orders->addFieldToFilter('total_paid',Array('eq'=>30));  //would find all the orders that were 30 
//syntax to find all the orders whose total_paid value is equal to it's grand_total attribute
//????????
```

The `non-eav` SQL concept I’m grasping for is:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders o WHERE o.total_paid = o.grand_total
```

Is this possible to do purely with object method calls, or do I need to do post-load filtering?

How do other `ORM` systems handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was waiting for a definite answer to this, but seeing as nothing's come up I might as well share what I've found out.
I traced addFieldToFilter and apparently every value you use ends up quoted so you can't really "hack" this by using the name of a column.
In fact I don't see any way to do this, at least not within this class.

Realistically I think you'll need to go with post-load filtering, at least for now. This of course is the very definition of inefficient code, but then again if computational efficiency was a priority, you wouldn't be using Magento in the first place...

Comment: Yeah, I suspect there's something (in a different method/class maybe) that would let you handle that. ORMs are great, undocumented ORMs not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to address this in one of my projects and came across this question while searching for a better resolution. My hack looks like this:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders->getSelect()
       ->where('total_paid=grand_total');
```

It annoys me that such a basic functionality of databases is overlooked by Magento's ORM.

Comment: I need to filter the order collection using a custom field(sales_code). But it through " Column not found" error

Answer (score 1):

There's a "polite" workaround for that.
See my example below where I am trying to filter where `created_at <= expire_at`.

```php
Mage::getSingleton('foo/bar')->getCollection()
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('expired', '(created_at >= expire_at)', ['created_at' , 'expire_at'])
            ->addFilter('(created_at >= expire_at)', 0)
```

It's stupid, but still solves the problem using the class.

PS: I hope that 11 years after publishing this question you've solved the problem. :D (Just a joke. I love your work.)